# Unable to update component queue in PCC- FileNet

Tags: filenet

I have created a component queue in PCC and added the required jars in PTM and it is working fine at production site, because of some server failure we moved the application to DR site, here we are not using DNS servers so I need to change the ip address in connection class, I changed and exported to jar file.
When I try to update the .jar files in the Adaptor Tab, the button Configure gets stucked and does not respond. For this reason I'm not able to update the .jar to the component. 
This thing happens with only one component queue, remaining all are updated and working fine.
Please let me know if you have any solution for this.![The exact step you can find in the below picture]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cheapest way is declaration needed host names locally to DR servers (I mean .../etc/hosts...)

Second options: place connections properties as file into Object Store, then you will be needed to change properties after disaster event.